# Can a lawyer advise a pro se litigant for technical purposes, without representing them?

Tags: bankruptcy, pro-se

May an attorney or legal advisor sit with a *pro se* litigant to advise on admissibility and/or rules in an Adversarial Chapter 11 proceeding?

Comment: If you are presumably paying this attorney or legal advisor for their advice, why not have them represent you?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is a function of local rules adopted by the U.S. Bankruptcy Court for the district where the action is pending. Those rules are not uniform.

Usually, the answer would be no. The federal courts have been reluctant to allow "limited representations" relative to the state courts.